# Select next row in dataframe in order to insert data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-entry

I have a data frame, for example:

```
   name    age
1 "Danny"  20
2 "Mitt"   35
3 "Dylan"  8
```

When I get new entry, I want to update this `df`.
I have used `nrow(df) + 1` for the next row:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1, ] <- c("Tom", 4)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `rbind`:

```
rbind(df,list("Tom",4))
```

check for `?rbind`:

> The functions cbind and rbind are S3 generic, with methods for data
>   frames. The data frame method will be used if at least one argument is
>   a data frame and the rest are vectors or matrices. There can be other
>   methods; in particular, there is one for time series objects. See the
>   section on ‘Dispatch’ for how the method to be used is selected. If
>   some of the arguments are of an S4 class, i.e., isS4(.) is true, S4
>   methods are sought also, and the hidden cbind / rbind functions from
>   package methods maybe called, which in turn build on cbind2 or rbind2,
>   respectively. In that case, deparse.level is obeyed, similarly to the
>   default method.
>
> In the default method, all the vectors/matrices must be atomic (see
>   vector) or lists. Expressions are not allowed. Language objects (such
>   as formulae and calls) and pairlists will be coerced to lists: other
>   objects (such as names and external pointers) will be included as
>   elements in a list result. Any classes the inputs might have are
>   discarded (in particular, factors are replaced by their internal
>   codes).
>
> If there are several matrix arguments, they must all have the same
>   number of columns (or rows) and this will be the number of columns (or
>   rows) of the result. If all the arguments are vectors, the number of
>   columns (rows) in the result is equal to the length of the longest
>   vector. Values in shorter arguments are recycled to achieve this
>   length (with a warning if they are recycled only fractionally).

Comment: Many thanks, I am aware of rbind, but I thought there is another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest you the `add_row` function from the `tibble` package. You could do it simply as follows:

```
df = add_row (df, name="Tom", age=4)
```